# how to make a task always run quiet from my build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

One of my tasks in my build.gradle is interative and should always be run with the `-q` flag, e.g.

```
./gradlew -q MyTask
```

If there a way I can control this attribute from my build.gradle file so that even if the user forgets to use the `-q` flag, the build script will set it automatically?

Comment: Do you need to change the logging level for one particular task only? What about the rest of the task being run in the same build?

Comment: Ideally it would be just for the one task.

Comment: Then this is definitely not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible currently to change the logging level of gradle after the build has started.  You can discover the current value but it's readonly by time you can execute code.

The `LogLevel` can be accessed via the gradle object in scripts by it's  `startParamater`:

```
LogLevel level = gradle.startParameter.logLevel
println "Current logging level: $level"
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#getLogLevel--

Another note if you want to have logging that isn't always sent to the console then you could use gradle's built in logger

```
project.logger.info("my message that only prints if caller uses --info flag on command line")
```

then for your events you want in the console logger use the `lifecycle` level.

```
project.logger.lifecycle('my message that will always print')
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can now remind users to use the `-q` flag if they forget.

Comment: added a better way to log messages in your plugin / task