# How to make gradle output more concise?

Tags: java, gradle

Is it possible to make the output from task execution more concise?

In the following sample output, the emphasized part is totally useless. It doesn't help you solve the problem.
After a few days of research I learned that I can find help at gradle's website. I'm concerned I might not remember the switches to make the output more verbose, but it would take 5 minutes to relocate them with a search engine, so it's useless.

The task is running in an environment where I can only get the N last lines of the output, the rest is lost. So all these useless lines are potentially wasting space for no reason, and precious information to solve the problem may be lost.

I would like to remove this emphasized part. Is it possible?
Can I re-enable these additional explanations only when I explicitly request for them; when there is a problem I really don't know about? Can I keep it disabled until I need it?

Sample output:

```
> Task :compileJava  
C:\...\package\subpackage\SomeClass.java:110: error: cannot find symbol  
someVariable.someMethd(someParameter);  
                                ^  
  symbol:   method someMethd(String)  
  location: class SomeClass  
1 error  
   
> Task :compileJava FAILED`  
   
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  
   
* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.  
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.  
   
* Try: 
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug  
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.  
   
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org**  
   
BUILD FAILED in 53s  
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: Well according to the gradle docs you can add -q to your gradle command to get it in quiet mode, however, there may not be a way to have this always active unless you remember the command. Try what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476772/how-to-make-a-task-always-run-quiet-from-my-build-gradle).

Comment: Sadly, `-q` doesn't seem to do what I want. The "what goes wrong", "try" and go to website parts are still printed. IN fact it doesn't seem to remove much.

Comment: You could try using a `grep` or `findstr` on your output to get exactly what you want. Grep and findstr return only the lines that contain the keywords you're looking for. Learn how to use both: [grep](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19504-01/802-5826/6i9iclf5k/index.html#:~:text=To%20use%20grep%20as%20a,for%20pipe%20is%20%22%20%7C%20%22.) and [findstr](https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-grep-equivalent-cmd-powershell/). Check section 4.1.1 to see how to use grep as a filter.

Comment: I already know grep, use it regularely, and thought about it, but how do I tell it "once you have found X, ignore everything until Y" ?  The difficulty here is that I don't have any real keyword present on each line I want to print or not print.